# Show desktop icon in Ubuntu 17.10 dock

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, dock, ubuntu-dock

How do I add a "show desktop" icon to dock on Ubuntu 17.10 like it was on Unity? I know I can show desktop by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> but I need dock icon.

Comment: There is a Gnome extension [Show Desktop Button](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1194/show-desktop-button/) which adds such an icon to the top panel.